# Modifying the default return value of an object belonging to an extended class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, class

I am relatively new to the rails syntax. I have a LogString class

```
class LogString < Array
```

I do the following with it

```
logs = LogString.new
logs.push 'this happened'
logs.push 'that happened'
```

which works fine. i want to be able to just write only

```
logs
```

to return what would be logs.join( ' | ' )

so i am looking for a syntax something like the method log_string here

```
class LogString < Array
   def log_string
      self.join( ' | ' )
   end
end
```

but where log_string is automatically called when i simply write the class instance name: logs

how can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just reference an object and have it call a method on the object, but you can get pretty close.

If you override the `to_s` method (short for "to string"), you'll be able to do something like...

```
class LogString < Array
  def to_s
     self.join ' | '
  end
end

log = LogString.new
log << "message one"
log << "message two"

puts "#{log}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
  def to_s
    join '|'
  end
```

This will work in templates and some I/O ops where #to_s is called. It won't work in irb unless you also modify `#inspect`. (You could just have it call your new #to_s.)