# Calling a method every time an object is referenced

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have a class as follows

```
class MyClass < Array
  def clean_up
    #clean up array
  end
end
```

Here are some examples of its use:

```
obj = MyClass.new

#I call some methods on obj

a = obj           #1
obj               #2
obj.some_method   #3
f = obj[0]        #4
```

Is there any way for me to force `clean_up` to be called, ONLY when the object itself is being returned (i.e. no method calls on it).

More specifically, I want `clean_up` to be called in cases 1 & 2, but NOT in cases 3 & 4.

How would I go about doing this? Is there some implicit method I can override, or is there some functionality for this in the `Object` or `BasicObject` classes that I can take advantage of?

NOTE: In cases 1 and 2, the actual object is returned, but in cases 3 & 4, the object is not returned. See comments for info on what I'm specifically getting at.

Comment: What is the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @muistooshort `clean_up` is a resource intensive method. If only obj[x] (a single element) needs to be called, I can simply just clean up that single element, and then return it to user (by overriding the [] operator). 

However, if the full array is being asked for, I need to make sure every element of that array is "cleaned up" before I return it. And I only want to do this if the object (full array) is being asked for (i.e. case 1 and 2 above)

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you assuming that the return value of `obj.some_method` and `f = obj[0]` are not `obj`? If so, you have to write that.

Comment: @sawa That is correct, updated the question.

Comment: #1 and #2 don't do anything in terms of "requesting" elements. In case #1, `a` now points to `obj`, but it didn't copy it. In case #2, you haven't done anything at all. I believe to accomplish what you want you need to override `each` and possibly a few other methods in addition to `[]`

Answer (score 0):

You could define a method to access the object:

```
class MyClass < Array
  def clean_up
    puts 'cleaning up the array now'
  end

  def get
    clean_up
    self
  end
end

m = MyClass.new
m.get.class
# cleaning up the array now
# => MyClass
```

Comment: That is a solution, but the problem is that I don't have control over the use of the object. So I can't just get everyone to start using `m.get` in place of `m` everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can achieve that, since calling `obj` or `a = obj` does not calling actually the `obj (MyClass)` object. As much, you will be able to change what is printed in the console (if you are using it) but I guess this not what you want.

Here are some interesting threads about similar questions:
[Modifying the default return value of an object belonging to an extended class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990815/modifying-the-default-return-value-of-an-object-belonging-to-an-extended-class)
[Ruby Class Return Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031723/ruby-class-return-value)